# How to set image only to a certain parallax section in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem with my coding on my website. Basically I've inserted the following html code on the page which is my section (section-743):

```
> <div>
>     <div>
>         <iframe width="315" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ucXRLnIkTyQ" frameborder="0"
> allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and then the following CSS to set the video into the static image:

```
div {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 67.5%;
    height: 0;
}
div iframe {
    body.home
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(http://www.ildottoredellepiante.it/formazione/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/laptop-png-6754.png) center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    padding: 1% 17.5% 19.8%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

How can I tell in CSS to show the image and video ONLY in the "section-743" of the website? Rather than like now is showing everywhere in blog post and other widget where it shouldn't show.

I've tried to add:

```
.section-743
```

and

```
#section-743
```

at the beginning of the CSS but unfortunately it didn't work. Any idea how can I fix this? Basically the laptop image should show ONLY in a parallax section of my website rather than anywhere else.

I look forward to hearing from you.

Thank you for your help in advance! It's a lot appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp

What you're looking for are ID and class selectors. These, however, are not magic, and require you to assign them to elements on your page.

I added IDs to the `DIV` tags from your example (and I added the closing `DIV` tags):

```
<div id="outerDiv">
    <div id="innerDiv">
        <iframe width="315" height="200" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ucXRLnIkTyQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, you can reference the `DIV` tags in your CSS like this:

```
#outerDiv {
    /* outer div style */
}
#innerDiv {
    /* outer div style */
}
#innerDiv iframe {
    /* iframe inside innerDiv style */
}
```

Notice that last one, which allows you to reference the `IFRAME` that is inside `innerDiv`.

Keep in mind that your IDs *must* be unique for the entire page.